# Adding drop shadow to side drawer in Xamarin Forms [Android]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So I was following the [Xamarin.Forms Master-Detail Page documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page). Everything is working fine but I noticed that the side drawer has no drop shadow when opened. After Googling about this, many articles/answers suggest that the default android drawer already has built-in drop shadow and should work out of the box. Code was needed to be added to iOS only to get the same effect.

**Current effect:**

[image]

**Desired effect:**

[image]

I must be missing something...

Comment: You should provide more information, regarding your code. Do you even have a detail page pushed?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro My code is a clone of the sample provided by the documentation link in the question. Available here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/MasterDetailPage - And yes, I have a detail page pushed.

Comment: Just wait for the XF 3.2 version where they introduce MaterialShel. Take a look at this repo https://github.com/davidortinau/Gastropods

Answer (score 0):

Your desired appearance is the default appearance for my app.

Does your MasterDetailPage look something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourCompany.Views.MainPage"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:YourCompany.Views">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <views:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:HomePage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Are you pushing it as a NavigationPage?

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```